# glDrawElements - how does it "consume" indices?

Tags: opengl, draw, indices

I am curious how glDrawElements uses it's indices. Let's say I have array of indices {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, drawn by GL_TRIANGLES. My question is, whether it forms 2 triangles by indices "123", "456" or 4 triangles "123", "234", "345", "456". I am importing .obj model, data are loaded as they should, but the rendering just gets messed up.

Comment: eh, i just messed up question, it should be "consume" not "consome" :)

Comment: So edit it and fix the spelling.

Comment: I missed the edit button before, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `GL_TRIANGLES` mode, it needs 3 vertices for every triangle, thus it will pull 3 indices at a time (so, it will draw the two triangles with indices 1,2,3 and 4,5,6).

Different figures apply if you have adjacency or draw a triangle *strip*, of course.

Also, since you mentioned that you are importing an OBJ file, do note that there may be **different** indices on vertices and texture coordinates and/or normals in the OBJ file.
This is not a bug, but a feature. This is allowable in OBJ, and many exporters do that when surfaces are smooth shaded (i.e. two faces share a normal) to conserve space.
You must construct a list of **unique** vertices, each with its own normal, texcoord, etc. and use the indices for these.

Comment: Thanks for the aditional info, but I have done that already. My result from importing is list of unique vertices, and array of indices forming one face (all of them are triangles) using the unique  verts. The actual problem is that Blender script to export into .obj files does not maintain vertex winding order, thus making normals face other way than they should. I think I will try exporting to .x file, will see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `GL_TRIANGLES` it will be `123, 456`. If you use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS` it will be `123, 234, 345, 456`.